# Implementing the transpose of a matrix using only `!!` and `length`

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, transpose

I'm trying to make up my mind on how to do a transpose of a matrix in Haskell using only `!!` and `length`. I have already written a function to get the column of a matrix at any given index `i`:

```hs
getCol :: [[Int]] -> Int -> [Int] 
getCol [] i = []
getCol (xs:xss) i = if isMatrix xss then (xs !! i) : getCol xss i else []
```

Plus, a function to return the length of a row:

```hs
rowLength :: [[Int]] -> Int
rowLength (x:xs) = length x
```

My plan right now is to fill a list `n` times with entries of `getCol`, with `n` being the `rowLength` of the list I call the function on.

So, for this sample list:

```hs
list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

-- rowLength ---> 3
-- then fill another list with every column of list, 
--     for the indices 0..n (with n being rowLength)
-- resulting in [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]
```

Problem is, I would normally do this with the `head` and `tail` functions, but I am only allowed to use `length` and `!!`.

My idea so far is

```hs
trav :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
trav xxs n = if (n <= rowLength) then getCol xxs n+1 : getCol xxs n else ?
```

my only issue is the `else` case. I know that it's mandatory in Haskell but I also know that my implementation doesn't make sense with an `else` case. This is my first time working with a functional language rather than an imperative one like Java, so I'm trying to somewhat simulate a loop here for the indices but don't know how to do that :(

Could anyone give me a tip? I would super appreciate that!!

Comment: Please do not use `(!!)`, it is quite inefficient: obtaining the *k*-th element requires *O(k)* time. Furthermore it is unsafe in the sense that if the index is less than zero, or greater than or equal to the length of the list, it will error.

Comment: I'm working on an exercise sheet, and it says I am only allowed to use !! and length :(

Comment: Are you allowed to use list comprehensions?  If not you will have to use recursion.

Comment: You'll need an extra helper function. You cannot do this with only a `trav :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]`  function. The helper should take `rowLength` and `n` (and maybe `xss`) as parameters, and produce a list of columns.

Comment: That's just what I'm trying to achieve, but I got stuck :( @luqui: I am actually able to use List comprehensions! Could I possibly incorporate the loop I wanted to do into a list comprehension using n (RowLength)? :o

Comment: @EmmaLee with a list comprehension you can "loop" over a range, calling a function for each one.  E.g. `[ n^2 | n <- [1..4] ] = [1,4,9,16]`.  So you could do this with `getCol`

Comment: Hint: if you have a matrix `m`, and call its transpose `m'`, then the thing that should go in `m' !! i !! j` is the thing that's currently in `m !! j !! i`.

Comment: As for “simulating a loop”, you can always translate imperative code to Haskell by replacing each control flow block with a *function*, and each mutable variable with a *parameter*; to “modify” a variable, you call a function with new arguments. E.g.: `upto :: Int -> [String]; upto n = reverse (loop [] 1) where { loop s i | i <= n = let { s' = ("loop #" ++ show i) : s } in loop s' (i + 1) | otherwise = s }` is akin to a `while (i <= n)` loop mutating `i` & `s`. This method may not produce the most idiomatic or efficient code, but it may help you get something working that you can then improve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `(!!)` or `length`; all you need is recursion, `(:)`, and pattern matching.

```hs
transpose :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
transpose [] = []
transpose ([]:xss) = []
transpose m = let (h, t) = ht m in h : transpose t
  where
    ht :: [[Int]] -> ([Int], [[Int]])
    ht [] = ([], [])
    ht ((x:xs):xss) = let (hs, ts) = ht xss in (x:hs, xs:ts)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BCsIwFET3PcUsXKRQA6IoBureM4Qsugik2MbSHzC3jz/V0OomP7wZmOc6ethhSCnMnafpSRZKQeu7D8Zgfyvfas21QcvPhghtVCSq//nIYLABwjUIOXWBWe/hoLDWQgW8nJ0tX@TOr4FYvk1BdWktHjzNyQqFiKxSF53POvE8ffc5yAZcyziS4iSNHaMW09z7gN1GTeuDlMc8cZLynO9Fyqsx6Q0)

`ht` is a helper function that gives `(heads, tails)` for a list of `[Int]`. It's like doing `(map head xss, map tail xss)`. The second equation takes a `[[Int]]` with a structure `firstList:rest`, finds the heads and tails `(hs, ts)` of the remaining lists `rest`, then appends the head and tail of `firstList` to `hs` and `ts`, respectively. The base case is with an empty matrix, where there are no more lists to find the heads and tails of.

The heads (the first element of the tuple) are the first column of the matrix (it's like doing `map (!!0)`). Thus, we have our first row `h` of the transposed matrix, and we prepend it to the result of transposing the rest of the columns (`t`, the tails). The base case is when all the inner lists are empty `([]:xss)`, so we return `[]`, the empty matrix. All of the other lists are assumed to be empty - **there is no verification that the input is indeed a matrix**. Extra elements in rows will be [silently ignored](https://tio.run/##XY7LCoMwFET3fsUsuohwhdjaV8Du@w0hCxeBSNWKCdS/tze2ou0muZwZmOMq/7BNM01hqDrfP72FUtD63gVjkN2WM1lzbVDysyFCGzV6n/7zlkFjA4QjhJi6wKzu4KCw1kICvJwdLP@InV8DMZ@0oHRpzR48zckKhRhZJV10Puue5/13n4NowLWIR684mdqKUYl@qLuA3UZN65ywJxziSkE4Ek6EjGHGNJdSEgoZwzPhQrgaM70B). The case `transpose []` is only for transposing empty matrices.

Since `(!!)` and `length` are not particularly efficient for linked lists (the former is O(m) to find the element at index k, and the latter is O(n)), I'd recommend avoiding them.

However, if you really want to try indexing, think about how you would generate the indices first. You'd need two lists, one for the row numbers, one for the column numbers. Once you have those, you need to swap them (`m!!i!!j` becomes `m!!j!!i` if `i` is a row number and `j` is a column number). For that, you could try recursion, list comprehensions, or both.

Comment: thank you!! but couldn't one simplify this by using !! and length?

Comment: @EmmaLee Perhaps you could use `!!` for getting the head, but that would make it *more* complex. I quite like it this way and don't know how to do it otherwise (without using `map`, etc.), but perhaps someone else will come up with a version that requires indexing.

Comment: Nice code, but I fear you have deprived the OP of a learning opportunity.

Comment: @luqui Mmm, you're right. The grace period's over, but I deleted that code.

Comment: thank you very much you guys! I could fully comprehend and re-construct your code @user and very much appreciated it!!! great for learning, but in the end the solution was, like luqui mentioned in the hint before, `transposal :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
transposal xss = [ (getCol xss i) | i <- [0..rowLength xss-1] ]` I just didn't know one could do this ;)

Answer (score 3):

Responding to my own question also because the solution was actually quite easier than I thought, using the functions I had already implemented myself.

```hs
trav :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
trav xss = transpose xss 0 

transpose :: [[Int]] -> Int -> [[Int]]
transpose xss n = if n < (rowLength xss) then getCol xss n : transpose xss (n+1)  else []
```

I didn't even realize that I don't need to simulate a loop. I had thought that in the `transpose` function, if it breaks down to the else-case eventually, it would merely return the empty list on its own. Little did I know this just puts it into the list that was already getting built up by the recursion!

[Try it out :)](https://tio.run/##bVDLTsMwELz7K6YSqhIBVisQiIggASckuHGzfMjBNBbGiWwD/vuwzqNJaX3xenZndsZ15T@VMV2n/VsVnI4oCgjxYoOUuHzAU9MYtu8JiRLv7lstoOiPwSwW0ecEG2V3oUZEWaJWplXuEdFjg/Ua@@noGZuah9upmC420z3sLJ2l92oFm4PR2anw3JjTMj2AaYSyaJIRcgJIiVyT7QTrj6U/j1ArmybSKp2jwEhKPQ1lvEpKjLnm93UwdmRh0Tv6H2IGV/38I43l0EqbSlBpfdvQuvTeoOeNyOnQs8aCaIeIFvfIZlt9@j7pIp2lsIfkzJ5vc0yhu69KJ7nWadp4ht6sEFvOr@QFxDXnN@m@5fxOyu4P)

Comment: you have discovered the use of "guarded" recursion to build the result list from the top down, lazily. ("guarded" because the recursive call is guarded behind a lazy data constructor). under strict evaluation, the corresponding concept is [tag:tailrecursion-modulo-cons].

Comment: for your amusement: https://pastebin.com/1KLKQRYL. :)

Comment: @user yes, I edited that paste because there was an error in the code. and since there's no edit option there, I had to create a new, corrected paste. so I removed the link to the previous, incorrect one. (several times in fact). :) btw the `traverse` code was a bit of a mind bender for me, when I discovered it. (don't remember if I've seen it somewhere or came up with it myself...)

Comment: @user *`traverse`* `(splitAt 1)`. --- btw there's another almost-one-liner, `foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat [])`, except it doesn't work for the empty case.

Comment: can I pin your paste for all the people wanting to implement a traversal ever to come? :P

Comment: I don't know what that means, but yes of course, use it as you wish. :) You might include an authorship note as e.g. "by https://stackoverflow.com/users/849891/will-ness". :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not what you asked about, and not at the level you're currently interested in, but as a curiosity this can also be defined as a one-liner,

```
transp :: Traversable t => t [a] -> [[a]]
--   or,                   [[a]] -> [[a]]
transp  =  takeWhile (not . null) . unfoldr (Just . traverse (splitAt 1))
```